# Android: How to programatically obtain billing period of a subscription product

Tags: android, in-app-billing

How do we programatically get the billing period (monthly/yearly) of a subscription product using android in-app billing? I would like to display the price of the product like this $0.99/mo. Since I am deploying my app in multiple countries, I would like it to be appropriately converted to local currency and style of representing a monthly charge ...